Problems with ScrollView and fixedSize modifer in SwiftUI
I'm having an UI contains an expandable ScrollView
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            Spacer()
            ScrollView {
                ExpandView()
            }
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Add")
                    Spacer()
                }
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        
    }
}

struct ExpandView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Accordion(title: "Red", content: {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .frame(height: 600)
            })
            Accordion(title: "Blue", content: {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.blue)
                    .frame(height: 600)
            })
        }
    }
}


struct Accordion<Content: View>: View {
    @State var isExpand: Bool = false
    let title: String
    @ViewBuilder let content: Content
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    isExpand.toggle()
                }
            }, label: {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(title)
                    Spacer()
                }
                
            })
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
            .frame(height: 44)
            .background(Color.yellow)
            if isExpand {
                content
                    .padding(.horizontal, 12)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .top))
            }
        }
        .clipped()
    }
}

Where user tap on Yellow Button, ScrollView will expand base on it content size. It works well if content size of ScrollView is small, but when it become larger. Button Add get pushed out of screen and  can not scroll anymore.
I have try to add frame(maxHeight: ) modifer but problem still occurs. I'm expect ScrollView's frame only expand upto top safearea and not push out Button Add
Here is a gif of current bug: https://i.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExNzkxeTYxYnFicHlhcWF4d3R6aXZpdzN0MjUzYWdhbW0wODdhNnQ3ZiZlcD12MV9pbnRlcm5hbF9naWZfYnlfaWQmY3Q9Zw/9D7qzWbgw79V4bY3TP/giphy.gif

It is almost always incorrect to put fixedSize on a scroll view. Seems like you just want to do ScrollView { ExpandView() }.defaultScrollAnchor(.bottom)?

Thanks for response, let me try your code

@Sweeper It works perfectly, thanks you. But why it is almost always incorrect  to put fixedSize on a scroll view?

Also defaultScrollAnchor is only available from ios 17. What is the solution for below version?

It is almost always incorrect to put fixedSize directly on a ScrollView, because the whole point of a ScrollView is to allow its contents to overflow its own bounds so that it can be scrolled, not to have the scroll view's frame be exactly the same as its contents.
If you want the scroll view's contents to start at the bottom, you can use defaultScrollAnchor:
VStack(spacing: 8) {
    ScrollView {
        ExpandView()
    }
    // 'for: .alignment' can be added in iOS 18+
    .defaultScrollAnchor(.bottom/*, for: .alignment*/)

    // ...
}

Alternatively, use a GeometryReader and set the frame(maxHeight:), then add another frame that positions the scroll view at the bottom of the GeometryReader, akin to what your Spacer did. Spacer wouldn't work here because GeometryReader is more "greedy" than Spacer and will take up all the space instead.
VStack(spacing: 8) {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        ScrollView {
            ExpandView()
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: geo.size.height)
        // here I set the max height before fixSize, so there is a limit as to how tall the scroll view can expand
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        .frame(height: geo.size.height, alignment: .bottom)
    }
}


Thanks. But why .frame(maxHeight: ) have to go before .fixedSize. I think if I put it below, it still meaning that ScrollView will have a maxHeight?

@duckSern1108 No. Think of frame as literally creating a "frame" around the view it is modifying. It does not directly change the size of the view. Some views like to expand to fill the frame, and some don't (e.g. those that are modified by fixedSize).

Great. Thanks for explain
